# I want to be able to scroll up/down within a page using the touchpad

Tags: windows-vista, touchpad, scrolling

I use to have my touchpad scroll up/down and even left/right.  I had to reinstall Windows Vista, update all windows updates and cannot figure out how to add scrolling options or download another driver to support scrolling.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which laptop/device do you have? The drivers and their settings vary from vendor to vendor.

Comment: Only doing a Windows Update after (re)installing a Windows OS is **not** enough. You probably need to look for all drivers to make sure you get the latest versions. (though an exception could be the graphics driver)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Synaptics touchpad drivers installed (this is on xp, but probably similar enough to vista that you can figure it out) and your touchpad is capable of it...  control panel, mouse, device settings tab click settings and it will open up a Synaptics control panel with the settings you need.

If you don't have the Synaptics touchpad drivers installed go to the manufacturer's website for your laptop... they'll have the drivers.

Comment: Synaptics touchpad drive is the one you're looking for. If you can't find it on your manufacturer's website just look for a generic one, or take one from another laptop manufacturers site, it's almost always a very generic driver.